# Search/replacement in string

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace

I have a Perl program where the user enters some text, a search pattern and a replacement string.

I am using the the `s///` operator to replace the search pattern by the replacement string, but in this scenario, if the user enters capture variables (like `$1`) or backslash escapes (like `\u` or `\L`) in the replacement string, the replacement pattern should process these metacharacters but rather it is treating them as string characters.

I have the following code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

chomp(my $text =    <STDIN>);  #read the text
chomp(my $regex =   <STDIN>); #read the search pattern
chomp(my $replace = <STDIN>); #read the replacement pattern

$text=~s/$regex/$replace/g;  # do replacement

print $text,"\n";
```

The sample input for this code is

```
fred flintstone and wilma flintstone are good couples
(fred|wilma) flintstone
\u\L$1\E Flintstone
```

The output is for above code is

```
\u\L$1\E Flintstone and \u\L$1\E Flintstone are good couples
```

I have found a way to make this correct in the following code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

chomp(my $text    = <STDIN>);
chomp(my $regex   = <STDIN>);
chomp(my $replace = <STDIN>);

$replace = '"' . $replace . '"';   # creating the string as '"\u\L$1\E Flintstone"'

$text = ~s/$regex/$replace/gee; # applying double evaluation

print $text,"\n";
```

Now this code gives the correct output as

```
Fred Flintstone and Wilma Flintstone are good couples
```

I want to know if there is a better approach for this problem?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a better approach. You have to use the evaluate option in `s///`. Note though, that this might be dangerous if you don't trust the user.

Comment: See also [Using the ee modifier safely with the s/// operator when the right side is input from user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107353/using-the-ee-modifier-safely-with-the-s-operator-when-the-right-side-is-input)

Comment: .. and [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A double-quoted string cannot be interpolated without compiling it

The `/ee` modifier carries the same warnings as `eval`: it is always dangerous to execute code of any sort entered by the user, and even a simple string may contain a block consisting of any Perl code the user likes to enter, like `"my dangerous string @{ unlink glob '*.*'}"`

I suggest that you make use of the excellent [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate) module, which exports a `safe_interpolate` function that will use the [`Safe`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe) module to perform the interpolation in a "safe" compartment

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use String::Interpolate 'safe_interpolate';

my $text =    'fred flintstone and wilma flintstone are good couples';
my $regex =   '(fred|wilma) flintstone';
my $replace = '\u\L$1\E Flintstone';

$text =~ s/$regex/ safe_interpolate($replace) /eg;  # do replacement

print $text,"\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

(First, you shouldn't use `-w` anymore. It's been supplanted by the (lexically scoped, more predictable) `use warnings` pragma in 2000.)

For your problem, you could use [`replace`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#replace-STRING-REGEX-REPLACEMENT-FLAG) from the [Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge) module, which is "a clone of javascript's `String.prototype.replace`".

```
use Data::Munge qw(replace);

$text = replace($text, $regex, $replace, 'g');
```

This will expand things like `$&` or `$1`, but not backslash sequences such as `\u`. For that, you could specify your own expansion function, but then you'd have to parse and replace special sequences in your replacement string manually. For `$1` and friends, this is easy, but something like `\Ufoo\Q$1\Ebar\Ebaz` is hard to handle correctly, especially if `$1` contains `'\E'` (even perl itself has had problems in this area historically). But if you get that part working, it's easy to plug into `replace`.