# Perl: how to use string variables as search pattern and replacement in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to use string variables for both search pattern and replacement in regex. The expected output is like this,

```
$ perl -e '$a="abcdeabCde"; $a=~s/b(.)d/_$1$1_/g; print "$a\n"'
a_cc_ea_CC_e
```

But when I moved the pattern and replacement to a variable, `$1` was not evaluated.

```
$ perl -e '$a="abcdeabCde"; $p="b(.)d"; $r="_\$1\$1_"; $a=~s/$p/$r/g; print "$a\n"'
a_$1$1_ea_$1$1_e
```

When I use "ee" modifier, it gives errors.

```
$ perl -e '$a="abcdeabCde"; $p="b(.)d"; $r="_\$1\$1_"; $a=~s/$p/$r/gee; print "$a\n"'
Scalar found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "$1$1"
    (Missing operator before $1?)
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "$1_"
    (Missing operator before _?)
Scalar found where operator expected at (eval 2) line 1, near "$1$1"
    (Missing operator before $1?)
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 2) line 1, near "$1_"
    (Missing operator before _?)
aeae
```

What do I miss here?

---

### Edit

Both `$p` and `$r` are written by myself. What I need is to do multiple similar regex replacing without touching the perl code, so `$p` and `$r` have to be in a separate data file. I hope this file can be used with C++/python code later.
Here are some examples of `$p` and `$r`.

```
^(.*\D)?((19|18|20)\d\d)年   $1$2<digits>年
^(.*\D)?(0\d)年  $1$2<digits>年
([TKZGD])(\d+)/(\d+)([^\d/])    $1$2<digits>$3<digits>$4
([^/TKZGD\d])(\d+)/(\d+)([^/\d])    $1$3分之$2$4
```

Comment: Note there could be security issues with using the `ee`  modifier. See for example: [Using the ee modifier safely with the s/// operator when the right side is input from user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29107353/2173773)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks, though safety issue is not a main concern here. I have full control of the list.

Comment: Yes, you think you have control. Suddenly one day a typo sneaks in, and something bad happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `$p="b(.)d";` you are getting a string with literal characters `b(.)d`. In general, regex patterns are not preserved in quoted strings and may not have their expected meaning in a regex. However, see *Note* at the end.

This is what [qr operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) is for: `$p = qr/b(.)d/;` forms the string as a regular expression.

As for the replacement part and `/ee`, the problem is that `$r` is first evaluated, to yield `_$1$1_`, which is then evaluated as code. Alas, that is not valid Perl code. The `_` are barewords and even `$1$1` itself isn't valid (for example, `$1 . $1` would be).

The provided examples of `$r` have `$N`s mixed with text in various ways. One way to parse this is to extract all `$N` and all else into a list that maintains their order from the string. Then, that can be processed into a string that will be valid code. For example, we need

```
'$1_$2$3other'  -->  $1 . '_' . $2 . $3 . 'other'
```

which is valid Perl code that can be evaluated.

The part of breaking this up is helped by [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)'s capturing in the separator pattern.

```
sub repl {
    my ($r) = @_;

    my @terms = grep { $_ } split /(\$\d)/, $r;

    return join '.', map { /^\$/ ? $_ : q(') . $_ . q(') } @terms;
}
    
$var =~ s/$p/repl($r)/gee;
```

With capturing `/(...)/` in `split`'s pattern, the separators are returned as a part of the list. Thus this extracts from `$r` an array of terms which are either `$N` or other, in their original order and with everything (other than trailing whitespace) kept. This includes possible (leading) empty strings so those need be filtered out.

Then every term other than `$N`s is wrapped in `''`, so when they are all joined by `.` we get a valid Perl expression, as in the example above.

Then `/ee` will have this function return the string (such as above), and evaluate it as valid code.

We are told that safety of using `/ee` on external input is *not a concern* here. Still, this is something to keep in mind. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29108544/4653379), provided by [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%C3%A5kon-h%C3%A6gland) in a comment. Along with the discussion it also directs us to [String::Substitution](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erwstauner/String-Substitution-1.002/lib/String/Substitution.pm).  Its use is demonstrated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926624/4653379). Another way to approach this is with `replace` from [Data::Munge](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emauke/Data-Munge-0.096/lib/Data/Munge.pm)

For more discussion of `/ee` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator), with several useful answers.

---

*Note on using `"b(.)d"` for a regex pattern*

In this case, with parens and dot, their special meaning is maintained. Thanks to [kangshiyin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1957265/kangshiyin) for an early mention of this, and to [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%C3%A5kon-h%C3%A6gland) for asserting it. However, this is a special case. Double-quoted strings directly deny many patterns since interpolation is done -- for example, `"\w"` is just an escaped `w` (what is unrecognized). The *single* quotes should work, as there is no interpolation. Still, strings intended for use as regex patterns are best formed using `qr`, as we are getting a true regex. Then all modifiers may be used as well.

Comment: It seems `qr` is not required as my `$p` can be matched in the second case.  My problem is that both pattern and replacement string are read from file, and the number of `$N` is unknown, and depends on the number of parenthesis in the pattern string...

Comment: @kangshiyin  Ugh ... I thought there may be more to it.  But then, things do/may depend on details of the replacement.  What do you know about what `$r` may be?

Comment: @kangshiyin Can you decide how `$r` is composed in that file? The problem is that `$r = '$1'` can be double-evaluated -- first `$r` becomes literal `$1`, then `$1` is evaluated.  (This is `/ee`)  However, `$r = '_$1'` cannot work that way -- on the second evaluation it will choke on the bareword `_`.  Well, then we can set `$r = '$1'` and do `s/$p/q(_) . eval $r/ge` ... but this requires access to `$r`, or at least knowledge of what it looks like.

Comment: Yes, both `$p` and `$r` are written by myself. What I need is to do multiple arbitrary regex replacing without touching the perl code, so `$p` and `$r` are in a separate data file. I hope this file can be used with C++/python code later. I've added some examples of `$p` and `$r` in the question.

Comment: @kangshiyin Great, this helps, thank you.  I have to go now but will add to the answer in a few hours. Can you please clarify -- is unicode indeed involved? Or do those characters you edited get translated?   Can you also confirm, is `$r` _always_ of the form `$1$2<literal characters>`?

Comment: I will give more examples. I think it will be an open form. There are unicode involved - I use utf8 in all context. Thanks, please take your time.

Comment: @kangshiyin  Updated to your clarifications and edits, thank you.

Comment: *"When you do `$p="b(.)d"` ...  the parens and dot won't have the expected meaning"* In fact they will. Try for example:  `perl -E '$a="a.c"; $_="abcd";s/$a//;say'`

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Heh, surprise surprise.  I wonder why parens and dot work, since in general regex patters don't.  I'll update now, thank you very much!

Comment: @HåkonHægland Fixed, thank you again.  This is a puzzle for me!

Comment: Yeah it's pretty confusing :) But I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/392717/2173773) answer can give some more insight. Also see the documentation for [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for what is interpolated.

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Yeah -- they helped by reminding me of the whole thing. I myself was for years intent on using single quotes over `qr`.  Funny how one (I) can forget.  I didn't realize that what ticked me off  were _double_ quotes. Those I use only when I specifically _intend to_ interpolate, so it pushed me to go overboard.  Thank you!  Also, it's a good and informative link, I'll find a way to stick it in the post. I adjusted the explanation a bit further.