# Is there better way to save the substitution part of regular expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

```
$search_32bit  = '(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))';
$search_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit = 'A0 B0 C0 \2\3';
$replace_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;

        @repls_32 = (
                [ $search_32bit, $replace_32bit],
                );

$hex = "9090908071C312345678775566000000777777";

foreach my $r (@repls_32) {

        $hex_tmp = $hex;
        (my $s_sign, my $mat_pos) = eval "\$hex =~ s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/i;return (\$1, \$-[0])";
        $len = length($s_sign);
        $replaced_str = substr($hex, $mat_pos, $len);
        print "matched_str: $s_sign\n";
        print "mat_pos: $mat_pos\n";
        print "length: $len\n";
        print "replaced_str: $replaced_str\n";
}
```

output as below:

```
matched_str: 8071C312345678775566
mat_pos: 6
length: 20
replaced_str: A0B0C012345678775566
```

My question:

Is there better way to save the substitution part of regular expression(i.e. $replaced_str: A0B0C012345678775566)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to acquire the replacement string, presumably built dynamically as the regex runs

```
my $repl_str;
$str =~ s{$pattern}{ $repl_str = code-to-build-replacement }e;
```

A concrete example: pad the capture with periods

```
my $str = 'funny';

my $repl_str;
$str =~ s{ (.{3}) }{ $repl_str = '.' . $1 . '.' }ex;

say $repl_str;  #--> .fun.
say $str;       #--> .fun.ny
```

The point is that the assignment expression inside the replacement part *returns* as well (the value assigned), so the replacement string is still available for the regex; doing this doesn't break things. There is now another variable floating around though, but I don't think that there is a built-in regex variable for the replacement string.

Depending on the replacement, this won't always work by just adding that assignment; recall that with `/e` the replacement side is *code*. So what would be `.$1.` above in a "normal" replacement (without `/e`) had to be adjusted to valid code, where `'.'` strings are concatenated to the capture by the `.` operator, and then we can add assignment and run that.

I hope that you can adapt this to that `eval`, for which I have no idea why you'd need it -- other than to perhaps run code supplied from outside, as a string? Even then I'd expect that only parts of the regex are supplied and you still write the regex and can do the above.

A clarification of a some points in the question would help but hopefully this is useful as it stands.  (In the future consider building a simple and clear example for what you need, if possible.)

---

In this specific case, there is a complication where those `\1` (etc) appear to be meant to be capture groups.  Then they need be `$1` (etc), and need more work to use out of a variable

One way is to build the actual replacement string out of the given `$replace` string

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = shift // '9090908071C312345678558765432166aaaabbbb7700abc' ; 
say $str; 

my $search  = qr/8071C3(\S{8})55(\S{8})66(\S{8})77/; 
my $replace = q(A0B0C0$155$266$377);

my $repl_str;
$str =~ s/$search/$repl_str = build_repl($replace, $1, $2, $3)/e; 
# or use @{^CAPTURE} instead of $1,$2,$3 with perl-5.27.2 or newer

say $str; 
say $repl_str;

sub build_repl {
    my ($r, @captures) = @_; 

    my @terms = grep { $_ } split /(\$\d)/, $r; 

    # Terms that start with $ are $N's and are picked from input
    my $str = join '', map { /^\$/ ? shift(@captures) : $_ } @terms;
    return $str;
}
```

See a discussion below.<sup>†</sup>  This prints

```
9090908071C312345678558765432166aaaabbbb7700abc
909090A0B0C012345678558765432166aaaabbbb7700abc
A0B0C012345678558765432166aaaabbbb77
```

(This is correct, if hard to see.  Why such long and hard-to-read example in a question?)

I use [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) to build a regex pattern, but `''` (or `q()`) works here as well. Since 5.27.2 there is a builtin [@{^CAPTURE} variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@%7B%5ECAPTURE%7D) so perhaps can use that instead of the explicit `$1,$2,...` list.

A similar example with more explanation can be seen in
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41280344/4653379). There are other ways to organize code to build the replacement string of course, and there are useful libraries for that as well.

The sub above takes the captures and so has them on hand and can compose the replacement string.  That `/e` is needed so to run the sub out of a regex, once the captures are available.

The linked answer builds *code* and uses `/ee`.  Please read carefully about the warnings to that and follow links.  I don't see that that is needed here.

---

<sup>†</sup>  This is a discussion from comments of whether the above can be simplified.

Any variables in the replacement side, including `$N`, are evaluated and concatenated with any literal strings into a replacement string.

```
my $str = 'bc';
$str =~ s/(.)/a$1/;  #--> abc
```

But when the replacement-to-be is in a variable, it's different.   With

```
$r = "a$1";  # Interpreter doesn't know what "$1" is

$str =~ s/(.)/a$1/;  #--> Use of uninitialized value $1...
```

If we try with single quotes then that's what we get, mere literal characters `a` and `$` and `1`

```
$r = 'a$1';  # now it won't try to evaluate $1 ...

$str =~ s/(.)/a$1/;  #--> a$1c  (but it doesn't do it here either)
```

So how do we make it put `$1` in the replacement side *and* see it as a variable and evaluate it?

That's the kind of a thing the `/e` modifier is for, where the string in our variable now must have syntax of valid code. Yet this is still not enough to get `$1` evaluated; we need `/ee` for the whole job

```
$r = q('a'.$1);

$str =~ s/(.)/a$1/ee;  #--> abc  (that /ee is very unsafe)
```

But this got a bit complicated, and `$r` (`$replace` in the question) as given must be processed into valid code syntax, and we are opening a huge security hole since `/ee` evaluates any string as code and in that string then evaluates code.  (Follow links in a post linked in the text.)

Then why not just use a function to which we pass `$N`s, nicely evaluated so the function gets the actual captured strings. Then in the function we can parse `$r` and build our replacement string.

So what that `build_repl` is for *is* needed. (Which is why there are libraries for it.)

---

One way to try these things is with "one-liners" like

```
perl -wE'$_ = q(bc); $r = q(a$1); s/(.)/$r/; say'
```

and

```
perl -wE'$_ = q(bc); $r = q("a".$1); s/(.)/$r/ee; say'
```

That `q(...)` is the same as single-quotes while `qq(...)` is double quotes.

Comment: I've undeleted the comments, but [moved them to chat for archival](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238197/discussion-on-answer-by-zdim-is-there-better-way-to-save-the-substitution-part-o).

Comment: @SamuelLiew Oh -- thank you!  Copied to disk.  Has it become normal to just delete them? (Should I copy what I care about in the future?)

Comment: Some of the comments were flagged as no longer needed, which were removed by mods, and some of them were self-deleted. Luckily content here are soft-deleted, so we can restore them upon request.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's fix your bugs.

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( sub_modify );

my $search  = qr/(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))/xi;
my $replace = 'A0 B0 C0 $2$3' =~ s/\s+//gr;          # \1 should be $1 in replacement.

sub_modify($hex, $search, $replace);                 # Fix code injection bugs
```

This is equivalent to

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( sub_modify interpolate_match_vars );

my $search  = qr/(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))/xi;
my $replace = 'A0 B0 C0 $2$3' =~ s/\s+//gr;

sub_modify($hex, $search, sub { interpolate_match_vars($replace, @_) });
```

Now, it's just a question of saving the string.

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( sub_modify interpolate_match_vars );
 
my $search  = qr/(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))/xi;
my $replace = 'A0 B0 C0 $2$3' =~ s/\s+//gr;

my $replacement_str;
sub_modify($hex, $search, sub { $replacement_str = interpolate_match_vars($replace, @_) });
```

---

The above has a very inside-out feel, though. It can be turned inside out as follows:

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( interpolate_match_vars last_match_vars );
 
my $search  = qr/(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))/xi;
my $replace = 'A0 B0 C0 $2$3' =~ s/\s+//gr;

my $replacement_str;
if ($hex =~ $search) {
   $replacement_str =
      substr($hex, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]) =
         interpolate_match_vars($replace, last_match_vars());
}
```

This also makes saving the original match easy.

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( interpolate_match_vars last_match_vars );
 
my $search  = qr/(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))/xi;
my $replace = 'A0 B0 C0 $2$3' =~ s/\s+//gr;

my $match_str;
my $replacement_str;
if ($hex =~ $search) {
   my $match_ref = \substr($hex, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]);
   $match_str = $$match_ref;
   $replacement_str = interpolate_match_vars($replace, last_match_vars());
   $$match_ref = $replacement_str;
}
```

Comment: I have no root right, and I will ask IT's help try to install it and test it later, thanks.

Comment: Root isn't needed to install modules

Comment: The machine is not web connected, I'll ask IT help install it with CPAN and have a try when ready, many thanks.

Comment: @ ikegami  Installed module String::Substitutio succesfully finally. And the codes works. This is also a good solution, it's concise and easy to understand. By the way, would you show how to save the search part 8071C312345678775566 also? Thanks.

Comment: Save `$&` or `substr($hex, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0])`

Comment: @ ikegami   Sorry, missed some of your posts before. The issue is String::Substitution doesn't support $&, so have to compile regex twice, one is $hex =~ $search, another is interpolate_match_vars.

Comment: @ ikegami   Seems Data::Munge support $&, but I don't know how to save the substitution, did you have experience on this? Thanks.

Comment: @ ikegami  Sorry, maybe my understanding is not right, the regex only be compiled once instead of twice in the solution. Let's close this case, thanks a lot for your guidance  and help.