# How does Perl parse unquoted bare words? (barewords, identifiers)

Tags: perl, parsing

Unquoted words seem to have a great many meanings in Perl.

```
print STDERR $msg;

$hash{key}

func( param => $arg )

my $x = str;
```

How does one determine the meaning of these?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following chart shows how Perl resolves identifiers in order of descending priority.

It also applies to identifiers chained by `::` (or by `'` before 5.42) unless otherwise stated. I'll call these "qualified identifiers".

1. Syntactically-defined meaning, when syntactically expected.

   ```
    sub foo { }          # «foo» («sub» is covered later)
    sub main::foo { }    # «main::foo» («sub» is covered later)
    method Class         # «Class» («method» is covered later)
    method Some::Class   # «Some::Class» («method» is covered later)
    $foo
    $main::foo
    //i
    =head
    <<FOO
    Class::
    Some::Class::
    LABEL:
   ```
2. String literal, when followed by a `=>` or when the entirety of a hash index expression.

   *This doesn't apply to qualified identifiers.*

   ```
    my %h = ( a => 1 );
    $h{a}
   ```
3. Variable name, when the entirety of the dereference expression.

   ```
    ${foo}
    ${main::foo}
   ```

   Note that using the name of a keyword, named operator or declared sub will result in an `ambiguous use` warning.
4. Keyword.

   ```
    while (1) { }
    sub { }
    use
    __END__
   ```
5. Sub call, when the name of a previously imported sub.

   ```
    use Time::HiRes qw( time );
    time
    main::time
   ```
6. Invocation of a named list operator, named unary operator or named nullary operator.

   ```
    print $x, $y, $z;
    $c = chr $i;
    $t = time;
    $t = CORE::time;
   ```
7. Label, when used as the operand for `next`, `last`, `redo` or `goto`.

   *A qualified identifier treated as a label results in a compilation error since labels can't be qualified identifiers.*

   ```
    next LABEL;
   ```
8. Sub call or inlined constant, when the name of a previously declared sub or constant.

   ```
    sub foo { }
    foo                          # Calls sub «foo»
    main::foo                    # Calls sub «foo»

    sub bar;
    bar                          # Calls sub «bar»

    use constant FOO => 123;
    FOO                          # Replaced with the value of the constant.
   ```
9. Indirect method call, when followed by a possibly-qualified identifier, a possibly-qualified identifier suffixed with `::`, a scalar (incl array element or hash element) or a block.

   ```
    method Class           # Calls method «method» («Class» is covered earlier)
    method Some::Class     # Calls method «method» («Some::Class» is covered earlier)
    method Class::         # Calls method «method» («Class» is covered earlier)
    method Some::Class::   # Calls method «method» («Some::Class» is covered earlier)
    method $o              # Calls method «method»
    method { $o }          # Calls method «method»

    Base::method Class     # Calls method «Base::method» («Class» is covered earlier)
   ```

   You can use the [`no indirect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/indirect) pragma to warn when code is parsed this way.
10. Glob, when used as the operand for an operator expecting a file handle.

    ```
     open(FH, '>', $qfn) or die $!;      # Equivalent to open(*FH, ...) or ...;
     print FH "Hello, World!\n";         # Equivalent to print *FH ...;
     print main::FH "Hello, World!\n";   # Equivalent to print *main::FH ...;
    ```
11. String literal, in the following situations:

    - When used as the invocant of a direct method call.

      ```
        Class->method(@args)         # Uses the string «Class» as the invocant.
        Some::Class->method(@args)   # Uses the string «Some::Class» as the invocant.
      ```
    - When used as the operand for unary minus.

      ```
        -foo
        -foo::bar
      ```
    - When used as an argument for the a sub parameter with a prototype of `*`.

      ```
        sub myprint(*@);
        myprint(FH, "Hello, World\n");
        myprint(main::FH, "Hello, World\n");
      ```
12. String literal. This is disallowed by `use strict qw( subs );`.

Hopefully, I didn't miss any.

Thanks to @mosvy, @Grinnz and @stevesliva! Each has uncovered a few cases I had missed.

---

**CURRENTLY MISSING**:

- `SUBNAME` in `sort SUBNAME`.
- `BEGIN` and similar. They sometimes act as keyword, and sometimes as a declared sub.
- Importing a sub named `print` doesn't follow the above steps.

  ```
  $ perl -M5.010 -e'
     use subs qw( time );
     eval { time; };
     say $@ =~ /Undefined sub/ ? "ok" : "bad";
  '
  ok

  $ perl -M5.010 -e'
     use subs qw( system );
     eval { system; };
     say $@ =~ /Undefined sub/ ? "ok" : "bad";
  '
  ok

  $ perl -M5.010 -e'
     use subs qw( print );
     eval { print; };
     say $@ =~ /Undefined sub/ ? "ok" : "bad";
  '
  bad
  ```

  I don't know what makes that one special, and I don't know if there are others or not. I was guessing it's because `print` doesn't have a prototype, but `system` has no prototype either.

Comment: I have a strong feeling of deja-vu, but haven't you forgot the `package method args` sytax? `use strict; sub bar::foo {} foo bar foo bar`. And no, it's not the same as `print STDOUT`, because `print(STDOUT "foo\n")` works, but not `method(PKG "foo\n")` in general.

Comment: @mosvy That is [indirect object syntax](https://perldoc.pl/perlobj#Indirect-Object-Syntax) and it's actually `method package args`. As a corollary, some builtins like print/say and system/exec that take a first argument without a comma pretend to use indirect object syntax but are actually a parser special case.

Comment: I would also add there are some other special cases like the first argument of `sort` which takes a bareword as a sub name regardless of strict 'subs'.

Comment: @Grinnz my bad, I reversed them in the verbiage but the examples's OK ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, Both direct (`Class->method`) and indirect (`method Class`) are missing. I'll fix.  (Yeah, I've posted  this before, but it was in a footnote to a tangentially-related question, and I found myself wanting to link to it.)

Comment: @Grinnz `print` is covered ("Glob, when used as the operand for an operator expecting a file handle.") I'll add `sort`'s operand.

Comment: There's also the `${foo}` way of writing `$foo` (which is normally used in double-quote string literals, but works outside of them too). I'll add that too.

Comment: @ikegami Another special case that you might consider, the unary `-` applied to a bareword will stringify it.

Comment: @Grinnz, yup, definitely a separate case. If it was just a bareword being "negated" (just like how the value of `$x` is "negated" in `perl -e'use strict; my $x = "foo"; CORE::say -$x'`), then the following would fail with a strict error: `perl -e'use strict; my $x = -foo'`. I'm working on something else right now, but I'll update the answer later today or tomorrow. It requires a lot of testing to find out where everything falls!

Comment: @stevesliva, I think the `FOO` of `<<FOO` falls under syntactically-defined meaning. I'll add it as an example or as a separate item as appropriate. /// You mean like `=head`? That would be no different than `$foo`, which is the very first item on the list. I've added it as an example.

Comment: @ikegami - `here-doc` and `perlpod` (yes, `=head1` or `__END__` first) are just two situations where I've found myself looking at what appear to be a bunch of barewords... which I suppose are simply specially quoted multiline strings.  Perhaps also the *phase* barewords like `BEGIN` and `END`, and maybe *label* words?

Comment: @stevesliva, `BEGIN { }` is just like `while (1) { }`, I can add it as an example.

Comment: @stevesliva, `FOO:` is a good one. I'll add both `FOO:` and `next FOO`. // Re ""*true bareword*", Not by Perl's definition. "*A word that has no other interpretation in the grammar will be treated as if it were a quoted string. These are known as "barewords".*" And they are outlawed by `use strict qw( subs );`. `next FOO` falls into the "has other interpretation" category

Comment: @stevesliva, I suspect that `__END__` is no different than other keywords, but I'll double-check.

Comment: Note that BEGIN can also be written `sub BEGIN`, though it's not a regular subroutine. `END` and `__END__` are different (the former is akin to BEGIN, the latter is a special token similar to `__DATA__` that causes parsing to end)

Comment: @Grinnz, `sub BEGIN { }` is syntactically no different than an ordinary sub decleration, so that's not relevant here. /// I know what `__END__` does :) Even if it has a compile-time effect, that doesn't make it special here. `use` and `my` also have compile-time effects, for example.

Comment: @mosvy I've updated the answer in response to your comments.

Comment: @Grinnz I've updated the answer in response to your comments. altough I haven't incorporated `sort funcname LIST` yet. I'm apprehensive about touching that!

Comment: @stevesliva I've updated the answer in response to your comments. Turns out that labels were really interesting. `goto time;` tries to jump to `1572794637`, but `goto some_sub;` tries to jump to `some_sub`.

Comment: That's bizarre. `goto eval 'some_sub'` works but `goto some_sub` abends `Can't find label some_sub`

Comment: @stevesliva Yeah, that's what I was saying. `eval` in `goto eval 'some_sub'` is taken as a operator (#6), but `some_sub` in `goto some_sub` is taken as a label (#7), not a sub call (#9).