# new SomeModule::SomeName vs SomeModule::SomeName->new(), what's the difference?

Tags: perl

I'm very new to perl so you'll have to excuse my ignorance.

I'm working on a legacy project. I don't have a dedicated IDE, I'm using PHPStorm with a dedicated Perl plugin. 
When hovering over a `new` keyword I'm getting a warning `Using of fancy calls is not recommended, use TCO::AEMAP->new()`.

The code in question is

```
my $aemapper = new TCO::AEMAP();
```

Basically it's suggesting doing

```
my $aemapper = TCO::AEMAP->new();
```

Is there any merit to this claim or is it simply more of a convention? I can't find much on google since I'm not exactly sure what to look for.

Comment: I don't see why it would say "fancy". There is nothing fancy about the old style syntax. I wonder what linter this thing is using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new Foo` version is called *indirect object syntax*. It's an old-fashioned way of calling the constructor on a package, and it's discouraged in modern Perl. Here's a partial quote of the [relevant section in perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax).

> We recommend that you avoid this syntax, for several reasons.
>
> First, it can be confusing to read. In the above example, it's not
>   clear if save is a method provided by the File class or simply a
>   subroutine that expects a file object as its first argument.
>
> When used with class methods, the problem is even worse. Because Perl
>   allows subroutine names to be written as barewords, Perl has to guess
>   whether the bareword after the method is a class name or subroutine
>   name. In other words, Perl can resolve the syntax as either File->new(
>   $path, $data ) or new( File( $path, $data ) ) .
>
> To parse this code, Perl uses a heuristic based on what package names
>   it has seen, what subroutines exist in the current package, what
>   barewords it has previously seen, and other input. Needless to say,
>   heuristics can produce very surprising results!
>
> Older documentation (and some CPAN modules) encouraged this syntax,
>   particularly for constructors, so you may still find it in the wild.
>   However, we encourage you to avoid using it in new code.

The alternative is calling `new` as a *class method* on a package with the arrow, as in `Foo->new`. The arrow `->` does three things:

1. It looks up what's on its left-hand side. In this case, the bareword `Foo` looks looks like a package name. So Perl will see if it knows a package (or *namespace*) with that name.
2. It calls the method on the right-hand side of the arrow in that package it's just found.
3. It passes in the thing that's on the right, which in our case is `Foo`, the package name, as the first argument. That's why in the method declaration you will see `my ($class, @args) = @_` or similar.

For all other object oriented calls, it's typical to use the arrow syntax. But there is lots of old code around that uses indirect object syntax for `new`, and especially older modules on CPAN still use it in their documentation.

Both work, but the indirect object syntax is discouraged. Use `Foo->new` for new code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll stick to the old styling since all of the project uses that. I find consistency a lot better.

Comment: Re "*The alternative is calling new as a class method on a package*", They both do that. Just two different syntax for it.

Comment: @Andrei, The old style is error-prone and leads to very weird error messages when you do something wrong. Please don't. Consistency is good. But consistency is no excuse for doing bad things.

Comment: While I fully agree with you I simply can't go changing it through the whole project. Leaving aside the fact that it's quite big it's also stable. I highly doubt my merge request would get approved and no amount of me protesting will help.

Comment: @Andrei, I didn't say to go change everything. "If it ain't broke." But going forward, new method calls should use `$invocant->method` instead of `method $invocant`.

Comment: Well, I can at least bring it into discussion. See where that leads.

Comment: @Andrei, What about methods call where the invocant is an object. Do you use indirect notation for those? (`foo $aemapper` or `$aemapper->foo`?)

Comment: Also note that [it's planned to allow disabling indirect syntax](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/17477)

Comment: @Grinnz, Awesome! (Left a comment at the linked document.)

Comment: @Grinnz I don't think that removing that syntax is a great progress; even with `Foo->new` its not clear just by looking at it if the `Foo::new` method will be called or something else: `package Foo{sub new{}} sub Foo {bless[],"Bar"} Foo->new`

Comment: @mosvy There are many unclear parsing rules, and many of them are caused by the existence of this syntax. Indirect syntax has the exact same ambiguity with imported subs according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263206/how-does-perl-parse-unquoted-bare-words.