# Why does this snippet complain about 'Can't locate object method "this" via package "t"' and not just fail to run?

Tags: perl

Found a typo bug in an old script, but I don't understand how this line passes a perl -cw:

```
$ perl -w -e 'my $t = "t"; this{$t} '
Can't locate object method "this" via package "t" (perhaps you forgot to load "t"?) at -e line 1.
$ perl -w -e 'my $t; this{$t} '
Can't call method "this" on an undefined value at -e line 1.
```

The bug is the missing `$` sigil for a hash `%this` But why does perl think I'm trying reference an object here?

Comment: This looks like `Indirect Object Syntax`: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Call-Variations `new File $path, $data` vs. `File->new($path, $data)` Maybe in combination with `Dereferencing Method Call`?

Comment: This is answered by [How does Perl parse unquoted bare words?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263207/589924): Indirect method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'this{$t}'
this {
    $t
} ;

$ perl -we 'sub this{42} ; this{$t}'
Name "main::t" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $t in anonymous hash ({}) at -e line 1.

$ perl -we 'sub this{42} ; this{42,43}'
# No output
```

Perl is parsing `{$t}` as an anonymous hash reference and expecting `this` to be a subroutine that can accept the reference as an argument. After Perl fails to find a subroutine named `this`, it tries to see if the construction can be parsed as indirect object syntax. Namely, it identifies the object type of `{$t}` and looks for a method `this` in that object type's namespace. This is the last resolution method the parser tries, so when it fails you get the error message from that section of the parser.

Comment: Re "*Perl is parsing `{$t}` as an anonymous hash reference*", No it's not. A hash constructor can't follow a bareword. The parser treats its as the block of an indirect method call from the start. Perl uses an LR parser, not an LL parser, so backtracking is not a thing.

Comment: Re "*This is the last resolution method the parser tries, so when it fails you get the error message from that section of the parser.*", No. This is completely wrong. For starters, we're talking about a run-time error. The parser it not involved. It definitely doesn't try things until it tries a method call.

Comment: @ikegami you are correct that the parser isn't trying multiple things, but if the bareword is a compile-time existing subroutine, it will parse it as a sub call with a hashref argument; if not, it is parsed as an indirect object call (which fails at runtime)

Comment: @ysth, I was using the documented definition of bareword (a word that is treated as a string literal because it has no other meaning). By that definition, a sub name is not a bareword. But then again, neither is a method name. So "bareword" was an incorrect choice of word. When I said bareword, I actually meant "an identifier that's neither the name of an operator nor the name of a sub", so my corrected sentence is "A hash constructor can't follow a identifier that's neither the name of an operator nor the name of a sub."

Answer (score 2):

This is the `METHOD OBJECT` indirect object syntax.  `this{$t}` is like `this {$t}` or `this $t` or `$t->this`.

For a simple scalar variable invocant, the `{}` are optional, but if your invocant were some other expression, e.g. `$h{$t}`, `this $h{$t}` does not work; it has to be `$h{$t}->this` or `this { $h{$t} }`.