# Are curly braces around Variable name in Perl optional?

Tags: perl, syntax

In some perl code I saw the syntax `${varname}`. Except from the case of string interpolation, i.e., when used outside of `"..."`, and except the special case where `varname` would begin with a `^` ([see here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names)) I *think* it should be completely equivalent to `$varname`. This is what I guess, but could not find any reference to it. Can somebody help me with references about this question, or, if I'm wrong, explain to me what this syntax does? Many thanks.

Comment: It is equivalent to `$varname`, and it was indeed undocumented (outside of double-quoted string and regex literals) last time I checked. If anything, it's *incorrectly* documented. An identifier with no other meaning is considered a bareword, which it acts as a string literal for itself. So `${varname}` means `${"varname"}`. Except that's not true. `${varname}` works with lexical variables and when `use strict;` is used, but not `${"varname"}`. Also, `split` in `${split}` shouldn't be considered a use of `split`, but means `$split` (although this warns).

Comment: It's item #3 in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263207/589924) to [How does Perl parse unquoted bare words?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58263206/589924).

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, very interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I regard my question as duplicate, however, it still helped because the statement of optionality outside of string interpolation is quite hidden in the answers, as well as in the perl docs. Also it might be found easier by others who don't search for"$dxyabc".