# How can I export a subroutine from a Moose package?

Tags: perl, moose

How can I export a normal, non-OO subroutine from a Moose package? In a regular package, I'd do it with `Exporter`, `@ISA` and `@EXPORT`.

Comment: Moose shouldn't affect Exporter

Comment: Don't use `@ISA`. Use the more sensible interface introduced many many many years ago: `use Exporter qw( import );`

Comment: Once you `use Package;` you can also just use a full name, `Package::func`, in code.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, and thank you @ikegami for also pointing me to the preferred ISA alternative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moose is for building classes and roles. While you technically *can* also export functions, it's not necessarily the best idea.

Here's an example Moose class which also exports a function.

**MyApp/Widget.pm**

```perl
use v5.26;
use warnings;

package MyApp::Widget;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( is_widget );

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean -except => 'import';

has name => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1 );

sub is_widget {
    my $object = shift;
    blessed( $object ) and $object->isa( __PACKAGE__ );
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

Here's how you might use it:

```perl
use v5.26;
use warnings;
use MyApp::Widget qw( is_widget );

my $w = 'MyApp::Widget'->new( name => 'Foo' );
say is_widget( $w );
say $w->is_widget;
```

Note that even though `is_widget` was intended an exportable function, it can also be called as a method! In this case, that's a feature rather than a bug, but often that will be an inconvenience.

A better idea might be to create two separate packages: one for your class and one for your exportable functions.

**MyApp/Widget.pm**

```perl
use v5.26;
use warnings;

package MyApp::Widget;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

has name => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1 );

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

**MyApp/Util.pm**

```perl
use v5.26;
use warnings;

package MyApp::Util;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( is_widget );

use Scalar::Util qw( blessed );

sub is_widget {
    my $object = shift;
    blessed( $object ) and $object->isa( 'MyApp::Widget' );
}

1;
```

And you'd call use your packages like this:

```perl
use v5.26;
use warnings;
use MyApp::Widget;
use MyApp::Util qw( is_widget );

my $w = 'MyApp::Widget'->new( name => 'Foo' );
say is_widget( $w );
```

Because the Moose class and the Exporter are now cleanly separated, you can no longer call `$w->is_widget` — it's entirely a function and no longer a method.

Comment: Why is `MyApp::Widget` quoted in single quotes? Is there any difference between `'MyApp::Widget'->new()` and `MyApp::Widget->new()` ?

Comment: Re "*it's not necessarily the best idea.*",  Classes often export constants

Comment: @Håkon Hægland. They are different if `MyApp::Widget` is a sub. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58263206/589924) (#5 and #11)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the reference! So this could happen if I also had a `use MyApp` (in addition to `use MyApp::Widget`) and inside the `MyApp` package there happened to be a sub called `Widget`... Then, when I did `MyApp::Widget->new()` in the main script, the return value of the `Widget` sub in `MyApp.pm` would be used (not what the user intended, but still according to the rules of bare word parsing in Perl) as the invocant for the `new` call instead of the string `'MyApp::Widget'` ?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, yes

Comment: @ikegami, yeah, exporting constants is one of the less bad things to do. However, if you're exporting constants, that's often an indication you're doing something else suboptimally. Rather than `use Employee 'ROLE_MANAGER'; if ( $bob->role eq ROLE_MANAGER ) { ... }` it's better to do `if ( $bob->is_management ) { ... }` and even better to do `try { $bob->management_tasks( sub { ... } ) };`

Comment: `Socket->new( HostAddr => INADDR_ANY )`, `File->create( mode => O_RDWR )`, ...